# Recording sound as WAV on iphone

Tags: iphone, audio, core-audio

I am making an iPhone recording app that needs to submit the sound file as a .wav to an external server.

Starting from the SpeakHere example, I am able to record sound as a file, but only as .caf

Does anyone know how to record it as a wav instead? Or how to convert from .caf to .wav on the iphone? (The conversion must happen on the phone)

EDIT:

I'm wondering if anything can be done with using kAudioFileWAVEType instead of kAudioFileCAFType in AudioFileCreateWithURL

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yup, the key is kAudioFileWAVEType

```
AudioFileCreateWithURL (
            audioFileURL,
            kAudioFileWAVEType,
            &audioFormat,
            kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
            &audioFileID
        );
```

Changing to WAVE from CAF in the SpeakHere example causes the recording to be as wav. I also edit the same thing in the playback class, and changed the filename to be Recording.wav

Comment: Be carefully. AVAudioFileTypeKey with kAudioFileWAVEType is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/). It is a well used (including by Audacity) C library for working with lots of file formats. It supports read and write of a variety of CAF and WAV formats.

The [CAF File structure](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/MusicAudio/Reference/CAFSpec/CAF_overview/chapter_2_section_1.html) and [WAV format](http://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) are fairly similar. If the worst comes to the worst, converting shouldn't be too hard.

It would involve taking the Audio data chunk, and copying as is into the WAV file, and using the information in the Audio Description Chunk to add an equivalent *fmt* subchunk for the WAV file. It is fairly simple byte copying.

However, be aware (as Eric pointed out) there are licensing issues, see: [Can the Libsndfile library be used on the iPhone iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939268/can-the-libsndfile-library-be-used-on-the-iphone-ios)

Comment: Thanks. I used the WAV format link to confirm that the recording was working. I was having a problem sending data to my server.

Comment: I voted this down because the libsndfile can't be used on the iPhone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939268/can-the-libsndfile-library-be-used-on-the-iphone-ios

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You can still use it by linking statically into your code (or at least the answer you mention says so), but that is definitely worth mentioning in the answer here. I'll add it

Comment: Actually, you can't statically link it either, unless you provide object files or source code to end-users.