# Record Audio in.wav format

Tags: ios, audio-recording

How can I record audio in .WAV format in my iPhone application.Can any one help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AVAudioRecorder to record into .CAF format and then use Extended Audio File Services to convert CAF to WAV

You can also check this question:
[Recording sound as WAV on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570430/recording-sound-as-wav-on-iphone)